# Automapper nested relationship "back" mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Let's say I have a nested DTO, like this (in reality it is a lot more complex):

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDTO> Item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

that maps to:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

When mapping from the OrderDTO down to Order, I would like that the Order property from Item references its order, as to make something like `var order = item.Order;` possible.

Is there any way I can do that when mapping? Also, is it possible to configure that for all my nested mappings?

Comment: Using `BeforeMap` you can save the parent object in `context.Items` and then use that value in a resolver for the parent reference. If you respect a naming convention, you can use `ForAllMaps` to apply it wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it worked great! Care to post as a answer? Just one other thing, will I have to always have to pass ` Action<IMappingOperationOptions>` in the call to Map (or make a extension)?

Comment: Yes, you can make an extension method, `MapWithContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeforeMap` you can save the parent object in `context.Items` and then use that value in a resolver for the parent reference. If you respect a naming convention, you can use `ForAllMaps` to apply it wherever you need.