# AutoMapper - Nested mapping by sharing parent's information to child

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172196/automapper-nested-relationship-back-mapping) answer I got an error.
I have three classes, and their respective DTOs:

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public ClassC Value { get; set; }
    public List<ClassC> AltValues { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClassADto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ClassBDto
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public ClassCDto Value { get; set; }
    public List<ClassCDto> AltValues { get; set; }
}

public class ClassCDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following mapping configuration:

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    // the converter is registered in ServiceCollection
    public MyProfile(IValueConverter<string, string> valueConverter)
    {
        this.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassADto>().ReverseMap();

        this.CreateMap<ClassB, ClassBDto>()
            .BeforeMap((source, destination, context) =>
             {
               if (context.TryGetItems(out var items))
                 {
                    items["ClassBDto"] = source;
                 }
             })
            .ReverseMap();

        this.CreateMap<ClassC, ClassCDto>();

        this.CreateMap<ClassCDto, ClassC>()
            .ForMember(field => field.Name, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(valueConverter));

    }
}
```

And the converter itself:

```cs
public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter<string, string>
{
   private readonly IDateParser dateParser;

    public MyValueConverter(IDateParser parser)
    {
       this.parser = parser;
    }

    public string Convert(string sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (/*this is where I have to check the Type property of the parent ClassBDto*/) 
        {
           if (this.dateParser.TryParse(sourceMember, out var dt))
           {
               if (dt < SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
               {
                   return string.Empty;
               }

               return dt.ToString("O");
           }
        }

        return sourceMember;
    }
}
```

But when mapping, I inspected the `ResolutionContext` and got an error:

> Context.Items are only available when using a Map overload that takes Action! Consider using Context.TryGetItems instead.

I observed this error when I put a breakpoint on the `var retVal = sourceMember;` and observed the `ResolutionContext context` variable.

This is the screenshot of the observation:

[image: This is the screenshot of the observation]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards

Comment: I don't think this line is compilable `(ClassBDto)(context.Items["ClassBDto"]).Type == 1`

Comment: I've updated the code, so it represents the situation that I have in the real project

Comment: You should show your real use case at the beginning, even if you don't want to expose your real code, at least create an almost similar code that describes your use case. This could save more time.

Comment: sorry about that. Note taken! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/12.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolutioncontext-options-was-removed) stated starting from version 12, it restricts the accessing of `Context.Items`.

Also, you are only allowed to provide the additional value to `Context.Options` when calling map as [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper).

I don't see why you try to make it complicated, you can use the `.ForPath` to pass and assign value from the parent to the child field as below:

```cs
this.CreateMap<ClassB, ClassBDto>();
        
this.CreateMap<ClassBDto, ClassB>()
    .ForPath(
        dest => dest.Value.Name, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value.Name + (src.Type == 1 ? "Type is 1": ""))
    );

this.CreateMap<ClassCDto, ClassC>();
```

---

Considering your use case requiring accessing the value from the parent object, still `.ForPath` is one of the choices but its limitation is that you need to move the whole logic into it as the demo shown previously.

If you are looking for a solution that implements a resolver/converter class with your logic, it is not possible. Especially when working with the nested field, as the custom value converter/resolver, type converter doesn't support in `.ForPath`.

You should implement an [`IMappingAction`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#using-imappingaction) to handle such handling during the `AfterMap` action.

```cs
public class MapClassBDtoToClassBAction : IMappingAction<ClassBDto, ClassB>
{
    private readonly IDateParser dateParser;

    public MyTypeConverter(IDateParser parser)
    {
       this.dateParser = parser;
    }
    
    public void Process(ClassBDto src, ClassB dest, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (src.Type == 1)
        {           
            if (this.dateParser.TryParse(sourceMember, out var dt))
            {
                if (dt < SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
                {
                    dest.Value.Name = string.Empty;
                    return;
                }

                dest.Value.Name =  dt.ToString("O");
                return;
           }
           
           dest.Value.Name = src.Value.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

```
this.CreateMap<ClassBDto, ClassB>()
    .AfterMap<MapClassBDtoToClassBAction>();

this.CreateMap<ClassCDto, ClassC>();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ytPEBT)

Comment: thank you for you answer and demo! It should work as a charm. But as you see, here a provided a simplified version of what really things look like. For example the ValueConverter is a bit more complicated. The ClassB(Dto) have additional members of ClassC(Dto), and I want to apply the converter to that as well. I'll update the main question with example that is more close to my real scenario

Comment: Updated my answer. For your use case, you should look for `IMappingAction` to do all the actions based on the parent within the code block. Also, you may refer to my demo link for the illustration.

Comment: The proposed solution works for me! Thanks @Yong Shun